# How can I pass an array from JavaScript to Rust that has been compiled with Emscripten?

Tags: javascript, rust, emscripten

Below is my Rust and JavaScript code that I made based on [an example that calls C code from JavaScript with an array](http://kapadia.github.io/emscripten/2013/09/13/emscripten-pointers-and-pointers.html) and [an example that calls Rust functions from JavaScript without parameters](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/04-call-into-lib/).

**display-array.rs**

```
#![feature(link_args)]

#[link_args = "-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_display_array']"]
extern {}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn display_array(array: &[f32]) {
    println!("Rust - array size: {}", array.len());
    println!("Rust - array: {:?}", array);
}

fn main() {
    /* Intentionally left blank */
}
```

**callDisplayArray.js**

```
var Module = require("./display-array.js");

// Import function from Emscripten generated file
display_array = Module.cwrap('display_array', 'number', ['number']);

var data = new Float32Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

// Get data byte size, allocate memory on Emscripten heap, and get pointer
var nDataBytes = data.length * data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
var dataPtr = Module._malloc(nDataBytes);

// Copy data to Emscripten heap (directly accessed from Module.HEAPU8)
var dataHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, dataPtr, nDataBytes);
dataHeap.set(new Uint8Array(data.buffer));

console.log("Javascript - nDataBytes: " + nDataBytes + " , dataHeap.byteOffset: " + dataHeap.byteOffset + " , dataHeap: " + dataHeap);

display_array(dataHeap.byteOffset);
```

I have succesfully compiled the display-array.rs code into display-array.js by running:

```
rustc --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten display-array.rs
```

I run my Javascript code with command:

```
node callDisplayArray.js
```

Here are the debug messages:

```
Javascript - nDataBytes: 20 , dataHeap.byteOffset: 5260840 , dataHeap: 0,0,128,63,0,0,0,64,0,0,64,64,0,0,128,64,0,0,160,64

Rust - array size: 0

Rust - array: []
```

The array in Rust is empty. I'm new to both Rust and Emscripten so I'm really lost here. Perhaps I shouldn't be calling `Module._malloc` like it's called when using C with Emscripten, and instead use something else?

Comment: It could be because Rust slices are **not** the same thing as a C array.  You should not be using Rust-specific types (like `&[_]`) when talking over a C interface.  Try changing the function to take only C-compatible arguments instead, like `*const f32, usize`, and go from there.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use unstable link_args feature for this anymore - that article is outdated. Instead, just mark your function as "extern" (like you would to export it to C) and "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS" will be generated and passed to Emscripten automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I edited the code to use `*const f32` and now I am able to print the contents of the array:

```
pub fn display_array(array_ptr: *const f32, array_length: isize) {
    for offset in 0..array_length {
        unsafe { println!("Rust - value in array: {:?}", *array_ptr.offset(offset)); }
    }
}
```